# Can someone tell me what this these symbols mean?

Tags: translation

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

bought a storage unit full of collectable items and would like to know what era these dishes came from but they have Chinese markings and would like translated. 18 inch hand painted Chinese dish with this marking on it. Also a 16 inch Chinese hand painted plate too.

Answer (score 2):

turn the first picture anti-clockwise 90 degree, the six characters are:

“大清嘉慶年製”

roughly “made during the 5th emperor of 清 dynasty” (1796-1820)